# Is this a good Model for "Guaranteeing" Record Updates Don't Fail due to ROW_LOCK/Race Conditions?

Tags: soql, exception, locking, try-catch, for-update

**Background:** The `zqu__Quote__c` object in our org has two child objects from another managed package we use for eSignature and credit card capture. One of those two child objects collects the Credit Card GUID/Token, the other collects the Signature information (Sign Date,Signer Name, etc). We have a need to copy the Credit Card GUID and the Signer Information up to the Quote, but because this information lives on two child objects that are both updated nearly-simultaneously in separate transactions, we often hit a race condition and one of the two updates fails, which results in the quote not being processed.

Since these child records have a relationship to `zqu__Quote__c`, I never actually need to query for the Quotes when attempting to update them. I typically just do something like this:

```
quoteList.add(new zqu__Quote__c(Id = recId,Field_Name__c = :VAL);
update QuoteList;
```

I would like to ensure that in 99.9% of cases, both updates will be successful, to the point where I want to invoke another transaction to try again if the previous transaction couldn't get either a query lock or a DML lock.

> **I've created the below Queueable class to achieve this, and want to
>   know:**
>
> 1. Is this a good, recursive model that will continue to spawn new transactions until it successfully updates the records (barring any unrelated/unexpected DML Errors)?
> 2. Is it completely unnecessary to do the inner `try{}catch{}` for `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW` DmlExceptions under the presumption that I should never hit that error since my SOQL query obtained an exclusive lock?
> 3. Are there any additional checks or logic changes I should make to increase my success rate?

---

### Code:

```
public class updateQuotes implements Queueable {
    private Map<Id,zqu__Quote__c> quotes;

    public updateQuotes(Map<Id,zqu__Quote__c> quotes) {
        this.quotes = quotes;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        System.debug('Start ZQuoteUtil.updateQuotes');
        Boolean isLocked = false;
        Id recordId;
        List<zqu__Quote__c> quotesToUpdate = new List<zqu__Quote__c> ();
        List<Log__c> logs = new List<Log__c>();
        try{
            quotesToUpdate = [SELECT Id FROM zqu__Quote__c WHERE Id IN :quotes.keySet() 
                                 FOR UPDATE];
            for(zqu__Quote__c q : quotesToUpdate){
                recordId = q.Id;
                q = quotes.get(recordId);
            }
            try{
                update quotesToUpdate;
            }catch(DmlException e){
                String msg = e.getMessage();
                if(msg.containsIgnoreCase('UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW')){
                    isLocked = true;
                }else{
                    logs.add(LogUtil.createLog(LogUtil.ERROR_STR, msg,'ZQuoteUtil', 'updateQuotes'));
                }
            }
        }catch(QueryException e){
            isLocked = true;
        }

        if(isLocked){
            ZQuoteUtil.updateQuotes tryAgain = new ZQuoteUtil.updateQuotes(quotes);
            if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                System.enqueueJob(tryAgain);
            }
        }

        System.debug('End ZQuoteUtil.updateQuotes');
    }
}
```

Comment: N.B. (1) queueable constructor should just be Ids, not entire object (2) the retry by re-enqueuing will fail if the initial queueable was initiated by an async transaction (like a batchable as queue chain depth can't be > 1; (3) I would not use the Test.isRunningtest as you can't assert in test methods that your retry logic works - use a different gating mechanism

Comment: My concern would be running out of async executions in your 24hr limit reset period. I guess it depends how often you update these values. (I guess this is mitigated if you first try the DML operation in the normal flow and only resort to the queueable on lock failure.)

Comment: To get around the queueable initiation issue, mentioned by @cropredy, you can use a combination of future and queueable (alternating as needed). This does, of course, mean you really do have to only use IDs since futures can only accept simple parameters.

Comment: @cropredy Queuable methods can accept non-primitives (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm). In this case I prefer that it accepts objects because my intent is to pass the records with updated values to the queueable method for DML.The Test.IsRunningTest() is there based on this suggestion from sfdcfox: (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149541/how-to-write-test-class-for-chained-enqueued-jobs?rq=1) - has this changed since 2016?

Comment: @PhilW I looked at the `Limits` class to see if I could find where I'm at in relation to my current aSync Limit but it doesn't appear to be an option. I can't find any documentation regarding a 24hr async execution limit, can you provide further insight on that?

Comment: You'll find the 250,000 per 24hr limit documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). Search for "maximum number of asynchronous Apex method executions" in that page.

Comment: did you get this code to work? Specifically the try again? This might work for my use case and was wondering what was your final solution.

Comment: @disasterlooms I have been using the exact code outlined in my original question with solid success. You do need to be cautious of stack depth as mentioned in this comment chain so its important to understand all of the different ways your code may be invoked, but otherwise yes this has worked for me to resolve my race condition. The race condition bug was effectively squashed using this approach